Character tables of Coxeter Groups
I'm interested in character tables of (irreducible) Coxeter groups. Certainly the character tables of the symmetric groups $ W(A_n) \cong S_{n+1} $ are easy to obtain, as are the dihedral groups.
But what about the character table of $ W(B_n) $? For example I'm interested in the character table of $ W(B_8) $ the group of $ 8 \times 8 $ signed permutation matrices, which has order $ (2^8)(8!)=10 321 920 $
To repeat, my question is where do I find or how do I compute the character tables of (irreducible) Coxeter groups, especially the smaller ones such as my example $ W(B_8) $.
I'd be especially interested in a way to find character tables of/ manipulate Coxeter groups in GAP.

For Weyl groups of type $A$, $B$ and $D$ GAP has built-in generic parameterized tables via
CharacterTable("symmetric",n);
CharacterTable("weylb",n);
CharacterTable("weyld",n);

with n being replaced by your preferred positive integer. CharacterTable("W(E6)"); (and ditto for 7,8) do the E diagrams.
More generally, you could create the group (e.g. from the diagram), convert to a permutation representation, and calculate the character table for the group.
E.g. for Coxeter Diagram of type $F_4$:
gap> f:=FreeGroup("a","b","c","d");;
gap> rels:=ParseRelators(f,"a2,b2,c2,d2,(ac)2,(ad)2,(bd)2,(ab)3,(bc)4,(cd)3");;
gap> g:=f/rels;Size(g);
<fp group on the generators [ a, b, c, d ]>
1152
gap> h:=Image(IsomorphismPermGroup(g));;
gap> c:=CharacterTable(h);;Display(c);


Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was hoping for. Are there any similar GAP commands for complex reflection groups?

There are not generic parameterized examples, but you can get it from the group -- added example.
